# remove pattern before digits and keep those digits

Tags: r, regex

I have a string

```
text = "Math\n      \n      \n        600 rubles / 45 min."
text2 = "Math\n      \n      \n        in a group"
```

And I want to replace`\n      \n      \n` with `" "` only if digits are following. 
As a result, I want to have:

```
"Math 600 rubles / 45 min."
"Math\n      \n      \n        in a group"
```

I tried `gsub("\n      \n      \n        [\\d]", " ", text)`, but it replaces the first digit too.

Comment: `sub("\\s+(\\d)", " \\1", text)`

Comment: thanks! but now it splits the number "Math6 00 rubles / 45 min."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a pattern that will match 3 occurrences of `\n` followed with 6+ spaces and then capture the digit and replace with a backreference to the Group 1:

```
gsub("(?:\n {6,}){3}(\\d)", " \\1", text)
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/EVAP7B)

**Details**

- `(?:\n {6,}){3}` - 3 consecutive occurrences of:

  - `\n` - a newline
  - `{6,}` - 6 or more spaces
- `(\\d)` - Group 1 (referred to with `\1` from the replacement pattern): any digit.

Comment: Well, perhaps, even `(?:\n +){3}(\\d)` will work well, the main point is that the digit pattern should be captured and then restored with the `\1` backreference. Note that if the plan is to "shrink" 3 or more occurrences of `\n` + 2 or more spaces, it will look like `"(?:\n {2,}){3,}"`. If there may be tabs in between newlines, use ``"(?:\n[[:blank:]]{2,}){3,}"``

Answer (score 3):

I came up with the following pattern:

```
gsub("\\n[[:blank:]]*\\n[[:blank:]]*\\n[[:blank:]]*(\\d+)", " \\1", text)
```

This pattern matches three newlines, in succession, ending with a number.  It allows for an arbitrary and unfixed amount of whitespace between each newline.  This makes the match flexible, and helps to avoid a misfire from counting spaces incorrectly (or new incoming data not behaving as you expect).

The main problems I see with your current call to `gsub` is that you are using fixed width spaces in between newlines.  Also, `[\\d]` is never used in the replacement.  Hence, you are consuming that number but it won't show up the replacement.

### Demo

Comment: You say the *pattern matches three newlines*, but `\s*` matches an indefinite number of newlines in fact. It actually *requires* 3 newline symbol.

Comment: You may use `[[:blank:]]` instead, or use `\h` and pass `perl=TRUE`. Well, I think both approaches will work for the current scenario. OP did not precise the requirements.

Answer (score 2):

```
text =c("Math\n      \n      \n        600 rubles / 45 min.","Math\n      \n      \n        in a group")
gsub('((\n\\s+){1,})(?=\\d)',' ',text,perl=T)
#[1] "Math 600 rubles / 45 min."                "Math\n      \n      \n        in a group"
```

Comment: Nice approach to use a lookahead and not have to worry about consuming anything at all +1.